# UIScrollview scrolling issue with autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have UIImageView as a background image on UIViewcontroller and than UIScrollview upon it, I have scrolling issue when UIImageview is added on self.view.

> **Scroll perfectly scroll without imageView, but with imageview its not scrolling**

This is my storyboard view hierarchy

[image]

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/6LEd5wq) these constraint i have set

Comment: [Project link](https://github.com/bhumi3010/scrollView), u can download zip and check, when im going wrong.

Comment: thank u so much @EICaptain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your constraints, I had found just one mistake

You gave one equal height constraint to superview to your view inside scrollview because of that scrolling problem occurs.

**Solution**

Just delete that equal height constraint and give a simple height constraint.. for e.g. height = 550 like that .. and you are enable to scroll your view.